# i use ngx-color-picker when float right colorPicker is display like cut, how to fix?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is the Issue Screenshot:

[image: Issue]

Here is the [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-ngx-color-picker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

**Code**

```html
<mat-form-field style="float:right" >
  <input fornControlName="color"
    matInput
    [style.background]="color"
    autocomplete="off"
    [(colorPicker)]="color"
    [cpPosition]="'bottom'"
    placeholder="Colour" />
</mat-form-field>
```

> style="float:right"

Comment: Please format your post properly.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-ngx-color-picker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts ----> see example.

Comment: I wanted to downvote, but still i will try to explain, when style float right is applied, at the bottom try scrolling horizontally

Comment: moreover adding style to a component is bad practice